# Hibernate and H2 no dialect mapping for jdbc type 0

Tags: spring, hibernate, h2

Im running this Query via JpaRepository on MSSQL Server and it works fine

```
 SELECT TOP(8) * FROM (
SELECT distinct a.id as source_id
                , null as f_name
                , null as m_name
                , null as last_name
                , null as full_name           
                , a.name as business_name
                , a.dba_name as dba_name
                , ad.id as address_id
                , ad.line_1 as  address_line_1
                , ad.city_town as city
                , right(tr.code,2) as state
                , ad.zip_postal_code as postal_code
                , co.name as country_name
                , a.national_tax_ident as id_number
                , 'T' as id_number_type
                , null as date_of_birth
                , 'SuretyVP' as data_source_id
                , 'AGENT' as role_id
                , getdate() as cycle_date
                , 299 as create_user_id
                , getdate() as create_date
                , null as update_date
                , null as attention
                , 'agency' as entity_name
              from dbo.Agency a
               inner join dbo.agency_address ag on a.id = ag.agency_id
               inner join dbo.address ad on ad.id = ag.address_id
               inner join [AdminDB].[dbo].[countries] co
                  on ad.country_id = co.id
               inner join [AdminDB].[dbo].[territories] tr
                  on ad.state_province_territory_id = tr.id
               Where a.ofac_processed_ind = 0
               AND ag.address_type_id = 2
               AND ag.exp_date is null
               AND a.agency_status_id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT distinct c.id as source_id
                  , c.first_name as f_name
                  , c.middle_name as m_name
                  , c.last_name as last_name
                  , null as full_name
                  , null as business_name
                  , null as dba_name
                  , null as address_id
                  , null as address_line_1
                  , null as city
                  , null as state
                  , null as postal_code
                  , 'United States' as country_name
                  , null as id_number
                  , null as id_number_type
                  , null as date_of_birth
                  , 'SuretyVP' as data_source_id
                  , 'AGENT' as role_id
                  , getdate() as cycle_date
                  , 299 as create_user_id
                  , getdate() as create_date
                  , null as update_date
                  , null as attention,
                  'contact' as entity_name
               from dbo.Contact c
               inner join dbo.Agency_contact ac on c.id = ac.contact_id
               inner join dbo.agency a on ac.agency_id = a.id
               Where c.ofac_processed_ind = 0
               AND a.agency_status_id = 1
               ANd c.exp_date is null
               ANd ac.exp_date is null
               AND ac.contact_role_type_id = 12) as data
```

But when I try to Run integration test with this query against H2 DB I have the following error

```
No dialect mapping for jdbc type 0
```

Here is my H2 DB config `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test:SAMINTEGERATIONTEST;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=MSSQLServer`

I saw similar topics, but unfortunately didn't find solution for my problem.
I would be very grateful for any advice.Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`null as full_name`, `null as date_of_birth`, `null as update_date`, and `null as attention` don't have a data type in **both** first and second queries, therefore `UNION ALL` also can't determine the data type. H2 by itself doesn't care about this situation and assumes that these columns have a fake `NULL` data type and can have only `NULL` value. But your persistence libraries don't like it.

The simplest solution is to add a `CAST` to all these columns in one of the queries (or in both of them, if you wish, it doesn't matter):

```
CAST(null AS VARCHAR) as full_name,
…
CAST(null AS DATE) as date_of_birth,
…
```